# CIFS mount is not recoverable after sleep or hibernate

Tags: mount, suspend, fstab, hibernate, cifs

I have Linux Mint Mate 17.3. The following mount points are defined in my fstab:

```
//at.xxxxxx-it.net/ORG  /mnt/L  cifs    user,auto,credentials=/home/liptak/.cifs.secret 0   1
//at.xxxxxx-it.net/shared   /mnt/M  cifs    user,auto,credentials=/home/liptak/.cifs.secret 0   1
```

If I boot, it works. As soon as I put the computer to sleep or hibernate, then it does not work anymore.

```
liptak@vnwha-ent034 ~ $ ls -la /mnt/
összesen 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 febr  29 13:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 márc  30 10:14 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 dec   22 12:33 L
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 febr  29 13:33 M
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 febr  29 13:33 U
```

I tried the followings:

- `ls /mnt/L` -> hangs, cannot be interrupted
- `sudo mount -a` -> hangs
- `sudo umount -a -t cifs` -> `umount: /mnt/L: device is busy`.
- `lsof | grep /mnt/L` -> hangs
- `fuser -km /mnt/L` -> hangs, cannot be interrupted
- `sudo umount -f /mnt/L` -> `/mnt/L: device or resource is busy`
- `sudo umount -l /mnt/L` -> returns normally, but then a `sudo mount -a` hangs again.

What do I wrong here? How could I investigate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an issue with this share, you can unmount it on hibernate/suspend and remount it on resume.
In order to do that you should create a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`, call it `50-share_handling` (for example), and put the next lines in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Unmount CIFS share on hibernate/suspend and remount it on resume

case "$1" in
        hibernate|suspend)
                umount /mnt/L
                umount /mnt/M
                ;;
        thaw|resume)
                mount /mnt/L
                mount /mnt/M
                ;;
        *) exit $NA
                ;;
esac
```

Make sure that it is executable.
More script examples can be found here: `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d`.

[Source](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation#Suspend_and_hibernate_configuration_in_Debian_Lenny) for Debian Lenny, should be valid for Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried it. After coming back from hibernate I get a black screen. I think this is not related to the re-mount, but I am not sure.

Comment: Remount shouldn't hinder the resuming process. You can comment out the strings containing `mount` in the `thaw|resume)` section of the script to verify that. Also in order to debug hibernation, refer to the link I provided in my answer.